# Java Certificate Error while opening WSO2 analytics login screen, shows blue screen

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have hosted the instances of wso2 api manager as well as wso2 analytics in the same parent directory. wso2 api manager is working great, but I cannot access even the login screen of wso2 analytics after the configuration. When I inspected in the network tab of the browser, I can see the `Exception occurred :java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 10.12.2.5 found executing GET https://10.12.2.5:9443/api/am/admin/v1/custom-urls/carbon.super` error. I am using version 3.2.0 for both apim and analytics. I have configured both of them to point to the same apim db. Also, I have enabled the `ssoEnabled` to `true` in `auth.configs` section in `deployment.yaml` file. How can this error be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The above error may have occurred due to the hostname verification process [1] of the dashboard server when connecting to the Publisher profile of the APIM server.

As a temporary solution, you can set the `hostnameVerificationEnabled` to `false` in the `<WSO2_API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml` file of the dashboard profile which will skip the hostname verification process.

(But skipping the hostname verification is not recommended in the prod environment, and hence you have to configure hostnames of the deployment according to your Common Name(CN)/Subject Alternative Name(SAN))

[1] https://lightbend.github.io/ssl-config/HostnameVerification.html

Comment: Thanks man, I can now login to see the dashboard. Will look into configuring hostnames. Thank you again. Cheers.